# Can not find System.Windows.Media

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Im creating a Windows Forms application using **C#** and **VS 2010 Express on .NET 4.0**

I need a media player in my app and Im trying to locate the Windows Media Control.

I went to Choose Items in the toolbox but no such reference exist and I also tried typing

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

but the .Media can not resolve.

Comment: `System.Windows.Media` is from `PresentationCore` of WPF. It is not for `Winforms` application.

Comment: OK, so Is the Media Player control the only player for media files by Microsoft ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following these instructions from Microsoft on [using the windows media play with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I see the WMP in COM objects I was wondering why  the Windows..Media namespace doesnt resolve ? But For this project the WMP Control will do also.